# Curl is not sending client certificate

Tags: ssl, curl, networking, client-certificates

I am trying to send a simple curl request:

```
curl -k -i --key ./key.pem --cert ./cert.pem https://target_ip/whatever/
```

The problem I'm having is that it does not send any certificate. The validation clearly passes as otherwise I was getting errors such as the key does not match but then I can see in wireshark that the certificates are not being sent in the TCP connection around Client Hello. Switches like `--verbose` or `--cacert` don't do much either.

I am able to send the very same certificates through postman successfully.

I have tried sending the same curl request from various sources such as my WSL2 ubuntu, a debian container in the cloud, a VM, ...

Any tips why it is not sending the certs?

**EDIT I - output from curl -v**

```
*   Trying 52.xxx.xxx.xx:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 52.xxx.xxx.xx (52.xxx.xxx.xx) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=NGINXIngressController
*  start date: Aug 10 18:08:13 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Aug 10 18:08:13 2021 GMT
*  issuer: CN=NGINXIngressController
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
> GET /whatever/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: custom.localhost.dev
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer  eyJ0...
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Server: nginx/1.19.0
Server: nginx/1.19.0
< Date: Mon, 10 Aug 2020 22:23:24 GMT
Date: Mon, 10 Aug 2020 22:23:24 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 153
Content-Length: 153
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive

<
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.19.0</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host 52.xxx.xxx.xx left intact
```

**EDIT II - wireshark captures**

It seems to be too much of a hassle to anonymise pcap, so here's just some snaps. Hopefully you'll be able to see all you need. I have highlighted the packet where I do (not) see the cert being sent. Note that I am running the postman on my windows workstation, whereas the curl is in the WSL2, hence the different source addresses. Other hosts for curl did behave the same though.

**Curl**

[image: Curl]

**Postman**

[image: Postman]

**EDIT III - Client Hellos**

**Curl**

[image: Curl]

**Postman**

[image: Postman]

Comment: Why are you using `-k` that's insecure mode - also is there a password associated with the key or cert?

Comment: *"... I can see in wireshark ..."* - do you see in Wireshark that the server actually requests a certificate (i.e. `CertificateRequest`)? Is the URL exactly the same as with postman? Can you provide debug output from `curl -v`?

Comment: @user3788685 The server has a self-signed certificate. I don't know how to provide it to curl as `--cacert` didn't seem to fix that issue. Hence the `-k`.
@SteffenUllrich No, the certificate is not requested as it is purely optional on the nginx server (`ssl_verify_client optional_no_ca;`). Yes, the URL is exactly the same. I will provide -v output in edited question.

Comment: @Trimack: *"...the certificate is not requested as it is purely optional on the nginx server (ssl_verify_client optional_no_ca;). "* - with this setting a certificate is still requested but an empty certificate is accepted as response. In general a client will never send a certificate unless explicitly requested.

Comment: The verbose output clearly shows no CertificateRequest from the server. That's why the client is not sending any client certificates. Can you please provide a packet capture from the failing curl connection and the successful postman connection so that one can see what the difference is?

Comment: The wireshark output shows that different IP and thus likely different servers and different URL are used. One server sends a CertificateRequest while the other does not. The size of the TLS server response is also larger for the server w/o CertificateRequest then for the other server which might even be caused by different certificates returned. Likely the problem is a difference in server configuration and not curl vs postman.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm sorry but where do you see those different IPs? I have blanked all the server IPs I hope. Just the clients should be visible. I do have most of the infrastructure under control, am running single server, and the server IP was used in both packet capture filters.

Thank you for pointing out that CertificateRequest but I still don't understand why it appears in one and not in the other. Could Postman inject that? I'd think that would not be captured by Wireshark then...

Comment: @Trimack: I might have been confused with the IP. *"Could Postman inject that?"* - no, the CertificateRequest is send by the server, not by the client (postman, curl). If this is the same server then likely postman and curl trigger different parts of the server configuration, for example because the are using different hostnames or one is using SNI and the other not etc. Details might be seen in the ClientHello, but the currently provided information are not sufficient for this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich From logs on the server I can see they are hitting the same configuration. They are also both using IP the request with identical Host header to match the target virtual server. I will upload shortly newly captured Client Hello details. I can see differences there in the extensions used but wonder which one makes the difference to get server request the certificate and why there are those differences.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ClientHello shows a clear difference: postman uses the `server_name` extension (SNI) to provide the expected hostname while curl does not.

This likely triggers a different part of the configuration in the web server: postman triggers access to the specific virtual host given as `server_name` while curl will probably run into the default configuration. Assuming that only the specific virtual host enables client certificates  this explains why the CertificateRequest is send by the server only to postman but not to curl.

It is unclear what this hostname is, but based on the length it cannot be an IP address. Thus postman somehow must know the expected hostname of the server even though it is claimed that the access was done with `https://target_ip/` only, i.e. without a given hostname. curl cannot derive from this URL the expected hostname and thus cannot set `server_name`. To make curl be aware of the hostname to set `server_name` while still being able to access a specific IP use the `--resolve` option:

```
curl --resolve hostname:443:target_ip https://hostname/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You got it spot on. Just to provide further explanation here: When the Client Hello comes in, Nginx has to select a server block and certificate to issue. At this point it doesn't have the `Host` header yet and apparently decides based on the SNI which Postman does magically populate while curl does not. Hence for TLS handshake the configuration (server block) is different from the one that then handles the HTTP based on the header.

Comment: @Trimack: Yes, that's the whole point of SNI - have the target name inside the TLS handshake already so that configuration (including certificate) can be picked based on the requested name when having multiple names on the same IP address.